# How to configure vim such that `_` is also counted as part of a word?

Tags: vim, unicode

According to the Unicode standard, `_` (the underscore character) is part of a word. This means that when you skip your cursor to the next word (in many interfaces you can do this with Ctrl + the arrow keys) you will skip over all the `_` characters as well as the letters and numbers in-between.

However, vim (where moving to the next/previous word is done using `w` or `b` in normal mode) regards `my_variable_name` not as one word, but as five: `"my", "_", "variable", "_", "name"`.

I would like to configure Vim's behaviour such that `_` is also properly considered a word character. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my `vim` the underscore character is considered part of the word, i.e. is skipped when moving back and forth with `w` and `b`. This behaviour can be altered with `:set iskeyword-=_` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297983/7659430).